# How to set user/admin accounts for a redirect after log in? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My problem with this code is that the IF statement which is deciding what page to go to seems to default to index.php. I have made a login table in MySQL already and have username/password column, and another column with a boolean value which states if the user is admin.

```
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    } else {
// Define $username and $password
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
        $connection = mysql_connect(" ", " ", " ", " ");

// Selecting Database
        $db = mysql_select_db(" ", $connection);

// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $auth = $row['admin'];
        if ($count == 1) {
            if ($auth['admin'] == 1) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $auth;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("location: member.php");
            } elseif ($auth['admin'] == 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $auth;
                header("location:index.php");
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    }
}
```

Comment: add this to the top of your php, and paste the errors here.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You don't need to start your session twice. It's enough to have one session_start() at the beginning of the file. Next time when you start the session it will cause the error.

Comment: `if (true) elseif (false)`? WHy not just `if (true) {...} else { ...}`?

Comment: try the php i posted in the answer below, just copy and paste and it should work for what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re wrote your login script. Try this.  I think you'll find this will work much better for what your doing.

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //$password = md5($password);

$db_host = "host"; $db_username = "username"; $db_pass = "password"; $db_name = "db_name"; mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass"); mysql_select_db("$db_name"); // connect to your database only if username is set

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
 $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if($login_check > 0){ // if the user exists run while loop below

session_start();  // start session here (only once)

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ // fetch the users admin from query

    $auth = $row['admin'];
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $auth; // set admin session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // set username session variable

    if($auth == 1){
        header("location: member.php"); // if user auth is 1, send to member
    }else if($auth == 0){
        header("location: index.php"); // if user auth is 0, send to index
    }

    exit();
}
} else {

header('Location: login.php'); // if user doesnt exist, reload login page.
}

mysql_close();

}
```

I recommend using md5 hash passwords.

When a person registers at your site, you can convert the password to md5 hash with this line `$password = md5($password);` prior to the db entry

Regarding your $auth above, this assumes your entry in the database is either a 0 or a 1.  If you are controlling it this way, i recommend using enum in the sql database.  set the type to "enum" and the type to '0', '1'

Comment: thank you very much this looks a lot cleaner but what else would I need to include for example closing off the sql connection as I tried to insert it but it returned some errors:(

Comment: add `mysql_close();` to the bottom of your php.

Comment: a good practice is to put your database connect script into a seperate php file and include it at the top of your php pages, and at the bottom add `mysql_close();`.  then all your php in between.  this will prevent any errors if you add php in the html or include php pages in the html.

Comment: I would be happy to assist with any php issues you might have.  and provide a more detailed explanation to eliminate any confusion you might have.

Comment: Okay thank you. I put in what you suggested, and it returned this error: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in ... line 42 :(

Comment: oops its because mysql_close(); happens when the page is loaded and there isnt a mysql connection until after you submit the form.  move `mysql_close();` to inside the } right above it .  i just updated the answer.  does this make sense?

Comment: I have to go to class.  I have been in your shoes before and its sometimes frustrating.  php is an ausome language but when your learning, it can take a while to figure out simple issues.  you are welcome to email me at aklooze@hotmail.com with future code issues.  also, if you are happy with my answer, can you please accept it.  thanks

Comment: Thank you very much I'm still getting some issues but that IF statement is fine! Thanks!

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?  are you using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your php?  That will print your errors.  i am curious what isnt working right cuz i just created a test db and tested this code and it worked for me.

Comment: any way you can send me a screen shot of your database table structure?

Comment: is there anywhere we could chat?

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow has a chat but you cant use it till your rep is 20 :/  I have a winter bike race to go to at noon but will be back after.  It would be easier to chat live and ill make sure your system is running smooth.  What is your email?  Do you have a gmail?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already extracted your `admin` value here:

```
$auth=$row['admin'];
```

You don't have to extract it here:

```
if($auth['admin']==1){
```

or here:

```
elseif($auth['admin']==0){
```

This simple change should fix your problem:

```
if($auth==1) {
    ...
} elseif($auth==0) {
    ...
```

In your original code, `$auth['admin']` doesn't exist because `$auth` itself is just an integer, so it will pass the `$auth['admin'] == 0` test since it is "falsy."

Also, it looks like you may have a case where `$auth` is completely undefined, in which case you should use "strict comparison" for that second condition, so you're looking for an actual zero and not just anything falsy:

```
} elseif($auth===0) {
```

Comment: Tried it but it still redirects to index.php for both admin and user, thanks anyway though!:-)

Comment: @DanAshton have you checked your `$row` to make sure the value of `admin` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: What do you mean. Anyway I now have a 'better' write up of my code but it still redirects admin to the same page:(

Comment: @DanAshton I mean add a `print_r($row);exit;` within your `while` loops to see if `admin` is `1` when you expect it to be `1`.

Comment: Yeah admin returns with a 1 on the end, while other users return 0 when I insert the print statement!

Comment: @DanAshton Explain "on the end" ? What are the possible values of `admin`? Of course, if you've already solved the problem, plz disregard :)

Comment: Array ( [0] => danashton [username] => danashton [1] => pass1 [password] => pass1 [2] => 0 [admin] => 0 )                                                          Array ( [0] => admin [username] => admin [1] => pass1 [password] => pass1 [2] => 1 [admin] => 1 )        - That is the two accounts when using the print code within the while loops, it detects admin has a '1'. When the Array begins it means there when i press login for that particular account not both at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        else
        {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
            $connection = mysql_connect(" ", " ", " ", " ");

            // Selecting Database
            $db = mysql_select_db(" ", $connection);

            // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
            $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            $row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

            $auth= (int)$row['admin'];

            if($count){
                if($auth == 1){

                    $_SESSION['admin']= $auth;
                    $_SESSION['username']= $username;
                    header("location: member.php");
                    exit;
                }elseif($auth == 0){

                    $_SESSION['admin']= $auth;
                    header("location:index.php");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
            }
            mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
header("Location: member.php");
exit;
```

Note the Capital L and the `exit;`

Also try `if($auth == "1")` and `elseif($auth == "0")` respectively.

If you value the security of your login page, use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql`. It is deprecated and insecure due to its vulnerability to SQL injection.

Also, take advantage of PhP's `password_hash` and `password_verify`when handling storage and verification of passwords. It is a lot more secure compared to `md5()`. If you'd like examples of usage, let me know.